# NodeJS: Why is there a two hour difference when Date is set as type?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to set a dateTime as a date type in typescript. But there is a two hours difference when it receives the dateTime from the frontend and I could see the date on the browser network hasn't changed. It changes only when it gets to my node js. This is how I declare my interface:

```
interface Idate {
  date: Date;
}
```

I send 2021-02-19T12:40:00+02:00 I get this 2021-02-19T10:40:00.000Z

If I set dateTime as a string it does not change, I mean there is no difference in dateTime.
Is there a way I can fix this without changing the type to a string?

Comment: Well, how do you transfer the date object? Can you give us more info?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but the date is being transferred as in a string format like {date: "2021-02-19T12:40:00+02:00 "}

Comment: Are you _sure_ you get +02:00 back? Date objects are often in UTC (end in Z or +00:00).

Comment: @RickN My bad, I get "2021-02-19T10:40:00.000Z" back

Answer (score 0):

I think it is converting to UTC, maybe you can send the date represented in milliseconds from front-end with getTime()